# Translating "Repurposes and depends on production of..."

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I wish to translate:

> Repurposes and depends on production of...

Word for word, the following represents my current effort:

1. Redivivus ("Recycle" but not specifically "Recycles" as required.) OR Regeneret (Regenerates) OR Recreare (Recreates).
2. et (and)
3. dependet (depends on)
4. productio (production)
5. of... (?)

By "repurpose" I simply mean to say "Makes a new use of" or "Reuses".

## Context

Sentence example:

> The new sales operation being established in Madrid will
>   ***repurpose*** the tangible assets and human resources of the older administrative operation based in Florence to the end that the former
>   becomes ***dependent on the production*** of the latter.

The specific phrase I'm translating will be used as an intermediary between flow-chart items.

[image: Flow-chart example]

The repurposing is prerequisite to production dependency.

Comment: Can you please use your phrase in a full example sentence? Context is key.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for both showing your work and updating to provide additional context!

Comment: @brianpck Please refer to the newly appended "Context" section of my question as per your request.

Comment: @ClarusDignus Out of curiosity, *why* exactly are you translating this into Latin? This is definitely "up there" in terms of translation difficulty to an ancient language.

Comment: @brianpck Thank you for qualifying the (in)feasibility of my translation request. I'm as of yet ignorant to what expectation of limitation I should have. I was expecting an easy melding of pre-baked idiomatic Latin expressions for "will repurpose x" and "will depend on production of x". The reason for my opting for Latin is but an attempt to standardise miscellaneous conventions within a flow-chart I'm editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little difficult without knowing exactly what you want to describe, but:

*Finem repetit novum atque de proferendo* (foll. by genitive) *pendet*.

Literally, [*an objective it seeks* [that is] *new and from the bringing forth* [of . . . ] *depends upon*.]

[edit] However, with your refinement of the problem it doesn't now seem that *production* is the word you want: would *resources* be better? If so, I suggest:

*Quo plus alter finem repetit novum, eo plus de subsidio alterius pendet.*

[So far as the one seeks a new purpose, by just so much does it depend on the other's assistance]. *Subsidium* is 'help that can be relied on', rather than simply 'help' (which is *auxilium*).

Comment: Shouldn't it be *de proferendo + abl*, e.g. *de proferendo vino*?

Comment: It would be easier if we knew where he wanted an emphasis. What you suggest is an example of gerundive attraction, which is perfectly all right. Silver Latin writers might use an accusative.

Comment: I've added further context to my question (sentence example and diagrammatic example of specific use).

Comment: I guess my comment was more about whether the genitive is permitted at all. I've never seen the objective genitive used with a gerund in this way...

Comment: Not sure about that one. I can't think of an example off-hand, though I've a dim memory about it being possible with gen. plurals. Whatever: the gerundive is much more attractive.